# Dynamically construct function calls with varying arguments using dplyr and NSE

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, nse

I want to be able to construct function calls dynamically with varying grouping variables/arguments using dplyr. The number of function calls may be quite large, which means the examples in the [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette are not practical. Ideally I want to be able to construct an object (e.g. a list) beforehand which stores the arguments/variables to be passed in each function call. Below is an example dataset, where we want to apply some summarising functions based on changing grouping variables.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(values = sample(x = 1:10, size = 10),
                 grouping_var1 = sample(x = letters[1:2], size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 grouping_var2 = sample(x = letters[24:26], size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 grouping_var3 = sample(x = LETTERS[1:2], size = 10, replace = TRUE))

> df
   values grouping_var1 grouping_var2 grouping_var3
1       9             a             x             B
2       4             a             z             B
3       7             a             x             A
4       1             a             x             B
5       2             a             x             A
6       5             b             x             A
7       3             b             y             B
8      10             b             x             A
9       6             b             x             B
10      8             a             y             B
```

Following the [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette we could come up with a solution like this:

```
f <- function(df, ...){
  group_var <- enquos(...)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!! group_var) %>%
    summarise_at(.vars = "values", .funs = sum) %>%
    print(n = 10)
}

> f(df, grouping_var1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  grouping_var1 values
  <fct>          <int>
1 a                 31
2 b                 24

> f(df, grouping_var1, grouping_var2)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   grouping_var1 [2]
  grouping_var1 grouping_var2 values
  <fct>         <fct>          <int>
1 a             x                 19
2 a             y                  8
3 a             z                  4
4 b             x                 21
5 b             y                  3
```

The example above is impractical and inflexible if I want to construct a large number of calls. Another limitation is that other information I may wish to include cannot easily be passed together or in addition to the grouping variables.

Assume I have a list containing grouping variables I want to pass in each function call. Assume also for each of those list elements there is a separate field with an "id" describing the grouping which was performed. See below for an example:

```
list(group_vars = list(c("grouping_var1"),
                       c("grouping_var1", "grouping_var2"),
                       c("grouping_var1", "grouping_var3")),
     group_ids = list("var_1",
                      c("var_1_2"),
                      c("var_1_3")))
```

How do I dynamically pass these lists of arguments/variables and ids to function calls and have them be successfully evaluated using dplyr? Let's say I want to create a column in the resulting dataframe which aside from the summarised data also contains the group_ids. For example if my `group_vars` were `c("grouping_var1", "grouping_var2")` and the `group_ids` was `"var_1_2"` for a specific function call I would expect the output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   grouping_var1 [2]
  grouping_var1 grouping_var2 values group_ids
  <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
1 a             x                 19 var_1_2  
2 a             y                  8 var_1_2  
3 a             z                  4 var_1_2  
4 b             x                 21 var_1_2  
5 b             y                  3 var_1_2
```

I am hoping to see a solution implementing this *without* using the nowadays deprecated `group_by_` functions which accept strings.

On an ending note, I feel it is rather discouraging that programming with dplyr in functions using NSE has such a barrier to entry. Anytime I get stuck with something that should be simple it takes hours to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "standard" tidyverse approach is here, as I never really have a sense of whether I'm "doing it right" when I try to write generalized tidyverse functions for my typical workflows, but here's another approach.*

First, we can generate a list of combinations of grouping columns, rather than hard-coding them. In this case, the list includes all possible combinations of 1, 2, or 3 grouping columns, but that can be pared back as needed.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate a list of combinations of grouping variables.
groups.list = map(1:3, ~combn(names(df)[map_lgl(df, ~!is.numeric(.))], .x, simplify=FALSE)) %>% 
  flatten
```

Below is a summary function that uses `group_by_at`, which can take strings, so there's no need for non-standard evaluation. In addition, we get the `group.ids` values from `group_vars` itself, so we don't need a separate parameter or argument (though this may need to be tweaked, depending on what you expect for the names of the grouping columns).

```
# Summarise for each combination of groups
# Generate group.ids from group_vars itself
f2 <- function(data, group_vars) {

  data %>%
    group_by_at(group_vars) %>%
    summarise(values=sum(values)) %>% 
    mutate(group.ids=paste0("var_", paste(str_extract(group_vars, "[0-9]"), collapse="_")))

  }
```

Now we can run the run the function on every element of `group.list`

```
map(groups.list, ~f2(df, .x))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   grouping_var1 values group.ids
>   <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 a                 31 var_1    
> 2 b                 24 var_1    
>
> [[2]]
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   grouping_var2 values group.ids
>   <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 x                 40 var_2    
> 2 y                 11 var_2    
> 3 z                  4 var_2    
>
> [[3]]
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   grouping_var3 values group.ids
>   <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 A                 24 var_3    
> 2 B                 31 var_3    
>
> [[4]]
> # A tibble: 5 x 4
> # Groups:   grouping_var1 [2]
>   grouping_var1 grouping_var2 values group.ids
>   <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 a             x                 19 var_1_2  
> 2 a             y                  8 var_1_2  
> 3 a             z                  4 var_1_2  
> 4 b             x                 21 var_1_2  
> 5 b             y                  3 var_1_2  
>
> [[5]]
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   grouping_var1 [2]
>   grouping_var1 grouping_var3 values group.ids
>   <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 a             A                  9 var_1_3  
> 2 a             B                 22 var_1_3  
> 3 b             A                 15 var_1_3  
> 4 b             B                  9 var_1_3  
>
> [[6]]
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   grouping_var2 [3]
>   grouping_var2 grouping_var3 values group.ids
>   <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 x             A                 24 var_2_3  
> 2 x             B                 16 var_2_3  
> 3 y             B                 11 var_2_3  
> 4 z             B                  4 var_2_3  
>
> [[7]]
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
> # Groups:   grouping_var1, grouping_var2 [5]
>   grouping_var1 grouping_var2 grouping_var3 values group.ids
>   <fct>         <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
> 1 a             x             A                  9 var_1_2_3
> 2 a             x             B                 10 var_1_2_3
> 3 a             y             B                  8 var_1_2_3
> 4 a             z             B                  4 var_1_2_3
> 5 b             x             A                 15 var_1_2_3
> 6 b             x             B                  6 var_1_2_3
> 7 b             y             B                  3 var_1_2_3
> ```

Or, if you want to combine all of the results, you could do something like this:

```
map(groups.list, ~f2(df, .x)) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, fct_explicit_na, na_level="All") %>% 
  select(group.ids, matches("grouping"), values)
```

> ```
>    group.ids grouping_var1 grouping_var2 grouping_var3 values
>    <chr>     <fct>         <fct>         <fct>          <int>
>  1 var_1     a             All           All               31
>  2 var_1     b             All           All               24
>  3 var_2     All           x             All               40
>  4 var_2     All           y             All               11
>  5 var_2     All           z             All                4
>  6 var_3     All           All           A                 24
>  7 var_3     All           All           B                 31
>  8 var_1_2   a             x             All               19
>  9 var_1_2   a             y             All                8
> 10 var_1_2   a             z             All                4
> 11 var_1_2   b             x             All               21
> 12 var_1_2   b             y             All                3
> 13 var_1_3   a             All           A                  9
> 14 var_1_3   a             All           B                 22
> 15 var_1_3   b             All           A                 15
> 16 var_1_3   b             All           B                  9
> 17 var_2_3   All           x             A                 24
> 18 var_2_3   All           x             B                 16
> 19 var_2_3   All           y             B                 11
> 20 var_2_3   All           z             B                  4
> 21 var_1_2_3 a             x             A                  9
> 22 var_1_2_3 a             x             B                 10
> 23 var_1_2_3 a             y             B                  8
> 24 var_1_2_3 a             z             B                  4
> 25 var_1_2_3 b             x             A                 15
> 26 var_1_2_3 b             x             B                  6
> 27 var_1_2_3 b             y             B                  3
> ```

- This question was cross-posted to [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dynamically-constructing-function-calls-using-dplyr-with-nse/58734) and I've added this answer there as well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution when passing lists of strings we want to use as grouping variables is to use `rlang::syms()`.

```
f <- function(df, group_var){
  # Allows us to pass dplyr variables as strings in a list
  my_group_vars <- syms(group_var$group_var) 

  df %>%
    group_by(!!! my_group_vars) %>%
    summarise_at(.vars = "values", .funs = sum) %>%
    mutate(group_ids = group_var$group_ids)
}

params_list <- list(
  list(group_var = c("grouping_var1"), group_ids = "var_1"),
  list(group_var = c("grouping_var1", "grouping_var2"), group_ids = "var_1_2"),
  list(group_var = c("grouping_var1", "grouping_var3"), group_ids = "var_1_3")
  )

lapply(params_list, f, df = df)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  grouping_var1 values group_ids
  <fct>          <int> <chr>    
1 a                 31 var_1    
2 b                 24 var_1    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   grouping_var1 [2]
  grouping_var1 grouping_var2 values group_ids
  <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
1 a             x                 19 var_1_2  
2 a             y                  8 var_1_2  
3 a             z                  4 var_1_2  
4 b             x                 21 var_1_2  
5 b             y                  3 var_1_2  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   grouping_var1 [2]
  grouping_var1 grouping_var3 values group_ids
  <fct>         <fct>          <int> <chr>    
1 a             A                  9 var_1_3  
2 a             B                 22 var_1_3  
3 b             A                 15 var_1_3  
4 b             B                  9 var_1_3
```